# Sort parent comments along with their child comments in backend

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to make a comment section in FastAPI using SQL Alchemy ORM at the backend for my website which contains many articles in the MySQL database.

I have 3 tables -> Users, Articles, and Comments. `user_id` and `article_id` are foreign keys to the comment table. Here for now they are hardcoded. I tried some recursive functions but that didn't work out well. Since databases can store and sort many rows efficiently, I prefer to sort the comments in the backend only.

I have the following `models.py` in FastAPI.

```
class Comments(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'comment'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
   text = Column(String(1000))
   user_id = Column(Integer)
   article_id = Column(Integer)
   created_date_time = Column(DateTime)
   parent_id = Column(Integer)
```

I found a one-liner SQL query that is somewhat close to what I need and works for replies to main comments (comments having parent_id = NULL) but doesn't work for replies to replies of the main comment and does not provide the required chronological order.

```
SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY COALESCE(parent_id, id);
```

I want to sort the data keeping the parent comments in reverse chronological order i.e. latest parent comment at the top and all its replies (replies to replies) with only one level of indentation just like on Instagram. Replies (replies to replies) are supposed to be in normal chronological order i.e first comments at the top and latest ones at the bottom. For example:

| id | text | user_id | article_id | created_date_time | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 3 | 28 | 41 | 2021-06-30 18:50:38 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 56 | 41 | 2021-06-27 10:00:04 | NULL |
| 3 | 2.1 | 28 | 41 | 2021-06-27 12:33:41 | 2 |
| 4 | 2.1.1 | 56 | 41 | 2021-06-28 20:07:09 | 3 |
| 5 | 2.2 | 12 | 41 | 2021-06-29 06:22:11 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 12 | 41 | 2021-06-27 09:20:44 | NULL |
| 6 | 1.1 | 28 | 41 | 2021-06-30 16:12:08 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

There might be some better way but you could do this with some sort of special marking/denormalization.

For example if you add "thread_created_on" and "thread_id" to the comments that record the top-most comment create date then you can tiebreak to get what you want.

```py
# RCO - reverse chronological order
# CO - chronological order
comments = session.query(Comments).order_by(
        Comments.thread_created_on.desc(), #threads together, RCO
        (Comments.thread_id == None).desc(), # True then False: thread comment top
        Comments.created_date_time.asc()) # nested comments CO)
```

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    UnicodeText,
    Integer,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint,
    update,
    DateTime
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Table,
    Column,
    MetaData,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)


class Comments(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'comment'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
   text = Column(String(1000))
   created_on = Column(DateTime)
   parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'), nullable=True)
   thread_created_on = Column(DateTime)
   thread_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'), nullable=True)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def created_on(d):
    return datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

with Session(engine) as session:
    d1 = created_on('2021-06-27 09:20:44')
    thread1 = Comments(text='1', id=1, thread_created_on=d1, created_on=d1)
    thread11 = Comments(text='1.1', id=6, parent_id=1, thread_id=1, thread_created_on=d1, created_on=created_on('2021-06-30 16:12:08'))
    d2 = created_on('2021-06-27 10:00:04')
    thread2 = Comments(text='2', id=2, thread_created_on=d2, created_on=d2)
    thread21 = Comments(text='2.1', id=3, thread_id=2, parent_id=2, thread_created_on=d2, created_on=created_on('2021-06-27 12:33:41'))
    thread211 = Comments(text='2.1.1', id=4, thread_id=2, parent_id=3, thread_created_on=d2, created_on=created_on('2021-06-28 20:07:09'))
    thread22 = Comments(text='2.3', id=5, thread_id=2, parent_id=2, thread_created_on=d2, created_on=created_on('2021-06-29 06:22:11'))
    d3 = created_on('2021-06-30 18:50:38')
    thread3 = Comments(text='3', id=7, thread_created_on=d3, created_on=d3)
    session.add_all([thread1, thread11, thread2, thread21, thread211, thread22, thread3])
    session.commit()
    from sqlalchemy import desc, nulls_first
    comments = session.query(Comments).order_by(
        Comments.thread_created_on.desc(), #threads together, RCO
        (Comments.thread_id == None).desc(), # True then False: thread comment top
        Comments.created_on.asc()) # nested comments CO)

    props = ('id', 'text', 'created_on', 'parent_id', 'thread_id', 'thread_created_on')
    fmt = ''.join(['%20s']*len(props))
    print (fmt % props)
    for comment in comments:
        print (fmt % tuple([getattr(comment, prop) for prop in props]))
```

```
                  id                text          created_on           parent_id           thread_id   thread_created_on
                   7                   3 2021-06-30 18:50:38                None                None 2021-06-30 18:50:38
                   2                   2 2021-06-27 10:00:04                None                None 2021-06-27 10:00:04
                   3                 2.1 2021-06-27 12:33:41                   2                   2 2021-06-27 10:00:04
                   4               2.1.1 2021-06-28 20:07:09                   3                   2 2021-06-27 10:00:04
                   5                 2.3 2021-06-29 06:22:11                   2                   2 2021-06-27 10:00:04
                   1                   1 2021-06-27 09:20:44                None                None 2021-06-27 09:20:44
                   6                 1.1 2021-06-30 16:12:08                   1                   1 2021-06-27 09:20:44
```

Comment: This approach makes sense in theory, but while trying it out in reality only the order by `thread_created_on` is getting executed and not the latter two, I don't know why.

Comment: @JoshinRexy forgot I made a full example, included it now

Comment: Really helpful. So close to what I need. But say, if I have a 2.1.2 comment (reply to replies) it would appear below 2.3 right and not below 2.1.1 since we are sorting on `created_on`?

Comment: @joshinrexy yes, I think I was confused about your descriptions, does the comment tree have a fixed depth? Ie. Only threads(1,2,3, etc), comments(1.1,2.1,etc) and replies to the comments(1.2.1)?  That is a lot easier to solve. Or can you have replies to replies to an indeterminate depth, sort of like Reddit?(ie. Like 1.2.1.1.1.1....)

Comment: I am thinking to have a non-fixed depth so that replies can appear just below its parent comment, but while displaying at the front-end, all replies and replies to replies would have one level of indentation, just like Instagram. Also, shouldn't there be a normal way to sort instead of duplicating field values for `thread_created_on` and `thread_id`. What would you suggest?